# Gitlab-runner job failed on Gitlab-CE using ssh-executor

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I've failed on running job by gitlab-runner from local machine using ssh-executor.

Meanwhile I can run `git clone git@mygitlab.myserver.com`, so as I think it's ok with my ssh setup. But when I try to run job using same machine as gitlab-runner it result with:

`Using SSH executor...
GitLab: Disallowed command
ERROR: Job failed: Process exited with: 1. Reason was:  ()`

In my `gitlab-shell.log`:

`gitlab-shell: Attempt to execute disallowed command <$'bash' $'--login'> by user with key`

My **GitLab** components:

`GitLab 9.3.6
GitLab Shell 5.1.1
GitLab Workhorse 2.1.1
GitLab API v4
Git 2.13.0
Ruby 2.3.3p222
Rails 4.2.8
postgresql 9.6.3`

**gitlab-runner**:

`Version:      9.3.0
Git revision: 3df822b
Git branch:   9-3-stable
GO version:   go1.7.5`

Hope you can help me to solve this issue. Thanks!